# Check IsCompleted from a void method with no return possible

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm trying to get my head around `async` and `await` i have been trying to implement it in some code of mine, what I have done so far:

**Code:**

```
        public async Task ExcecuteMacroCode(string _macroModeToUse, string[] _macroCode, string _site, Project _project)
        {
            try {
                string macroSelected = _macroModeToUse == "-[REG]" ? "-[REG]" : "-[LAP]";
                if (_macroModeToUse == macroSelected)
                {
                    foreach (string _macroCodeFile in _macroCode)
                    {
                        string[] code = _macroCodeFile.Split('|');

                        switch (code[0])
                        {
                            case "RJ_U":
                                string cleanUrl = code[1].Replace("{HOSTNAME}", _site);
                                browser.Load(cleanUrl);
                                panelBrowserMain.Controls.Add(browser);
                                browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                                browserMain.Text = cleanUrl;
                                browser.AddressChanged += Browser_AddressChanged;
                                break;
                            case "RJ_I":
                                //await Task.Run(() => {
                                //    return browser.ExecuteScriptAsyncWhenPageLoaded(GetAndReplaceMacro(code[1], _project));
                                //});
                                browser.ExecuteScriptAsyncWhenPageLoaded(GetAndReplaceMacro(code[1], _project));
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Helpers.DebugLogging($"[{DateTime.Now}]-[{ex}]");
            }
        }

        public async Task InitializeChromeBrowserAsync(ChromiumWebBrowser browser, string _macroModeToUse, string[] _macroCode, string _site, int _sitesCount, Project _project, Func<string, Tuple<string, string, string>> getUserPassEmail)
        {
            try
            {
                Task newTask = await ExcecuteMacroCode(_macroModeToUse, _macroCode, _site, _project);
                if (newTask.IsCompleted)
                {
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Helpers.DebugLogging($"[{DateTime.Now}]-[{ex}]");
            }
        }
```

The way i have set it up just now i'm getting the error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'` from my understanding it's because the `method await ExcecuteMacroCode` is not returning anything (which is right, i don't need anything returned really)

Is there a way i can still make sure the Task is completed so i can use the `newTask.IsCompleted` part, i'm not even sure i have set the code up correctly any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Remove the `Task newTask = ` and keep the rest of the line. You don't need to check for `IsCompleted`, if the `await` has returned then it is. If you still want to do that then `Task newTask = ExcecuteMacroCode(_macroModeToUse, _macroCode, _site, _project); await newTask; ...`, but that's kind of silly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to manually check if an awaited Task is completed or not. That's already done by the await operator.

The error is that this call `await _wellboreService.CreateWellboreSectionAsync(wellboreSection, CurrentUser)` is returning `void`, and you are trying to assign it to `Task newTask`.

When you `await` a task, the method is suspended and control is given to the parent caller until the Task is completed, and then it automatically resumes. After the await statement you know that the Task has, in fact, been completed because if not you wouldn't have reached that line in the execution. So **there is no need for manually checking the `IsCompleted` property of the Task.**

You could rewrite your code like this:

```
try
{
    await ExcecuteMacroCode(_macroModeToUse, _macroCode, _site, _project);
    this.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Helpers.DebugLogging($"[{DateTime.Now}]-[{ex}]");
}
```

You should check the [official documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model) for more clarifiation and examples such as this one:

```
public async Task<int> GetUrlContentLengthAsync()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();

    Task<string> getStringTask =
        client.GetStringAsync("https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet");

    DoIndependentWork();

    string contents = await getStringTask;

    return contents.Length;
}

void DoIndependentWork()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Working...");
}
```

Pay close attention to the await operator. It suspends `GetUrlContentLengthAsync`:

1. `GetUrlContentLengthAsync` can't continue until `getStringTask`
   is complete.
2. Meanwhile, control returns to the caller of
   `GetUrlContentLengthAsync`.
3. Control resumes here when
   `getStringTask` is complete.
4. The `await` operator then retrieves
   the string result from `getStringTask`.

Comment: Thank you very much, i'm getting better with it :)